# What's an easy way to lure enemies in MGS V: Ground Zeroes?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I used to play Metal Gear Solid: Peacewalker in which it is possible to tap/scratch the cover you are behind. This was a fast and easy way to attract an enemy's attention to grab them as soon as they reach the cover.

Does Metal Gear Solid V: Ground Zeroes have anything like this? I couldn't find anything that allowed me to "tap" cover like in Peacewalker, but maybe I just missed it.

If this isn't possible in the game, what are alternatives to easily lure enemies towards me?

It is possible to have enemies call others towards them, but for that I would first need an enemy which is a bit tricky and pretty much what I'm trying to achieve in the first place.

I could also throw an empty magazine on the ground, but that requires me to first switch equipment and aim which takes time and might get me spotted.

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way to make a sound in Ground Zeroes is throwing an empty magazine.  I recall them boasting that they'd added back in tapping on cover during one of the gameplay trailers for Phantom Pain.

Answer (score 1):

In GZ, the only way to lure enemies is to throw a magazine.

You can also fire a silenced weapon at the point you want to lure them, but it will often lead enemies to be alert.

Taping on wall/cover has been added in TPP.

Comment: Can you tap on the wall in TPP? I thought it was a "clacking" noise you made with your prosthetic arm.

Comment: @DangerZone You're right - The knock is made with Snake's arm.

Answer (score -5):

There is a prosthetic hand upgrade that allows it to make a sound to lure enemies towards the sound. It's kind of like knocking a wall but you can use it anywhere.

D Dog also has a bark command where u can set D Dog in place and command him to bark to lure enemies.

Comment: This information relates to MGS5: The Phantom Pain not MGS5: Ground Zeros asked in the question.

Comment: To be fair, the title did not specify Ground Zeros until recently edited. But still, this would not be an answer to this particular game.